# ASP.NET MVC - Display value for a coded field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After a few years off ASP.NET, I recently started to do a come back, especially with MVC.
Suppose you have a Movie Class like this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I changed the field Genre in the Create/Edit view so that user chooses from a selectbox according to the following:

```
1 = Action;
2 = Adventure;
3 = Comedy;
4 = Horror;
5 = Disaster;
6 = Political;
7 = Thriller;
```

Is there an easy way to display the corresponding "Human" value instead of the plain integer in a view/details page?

(In Django which I know very well, you just need `movie.get_Genre_display()`: [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) )

Comment: Does the property type have to be an integer? If it does, create a Dto object that has the string version, and map that property to it's correlated string representation

Comment: @CallumLinington Can you please put that in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an enum as string, then change it in model from int to YourEnumType:

```
public class Movie
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public GenreEnum Genre { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and in razor just write

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=> Model.Genre )
```

Comment: That looks like a good idea. Let me try this and come back to you

Answer (score 1):

I supose you display a DropDownList, so you can use an enum:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Genre", 
   Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Genre)) , 
   "Select My Type", 
   new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I figured this one out. My issue is with the display page. How to display Disaster instead of 5?

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear enough? For a given Movie object, @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre) shows a number. Is there a simple way to get it to show the corresponding "verbose" value? E.g. Disaster instead of 5, or Action instead of 1? Do you get my point now?

Comment: You can use Html. DropDownListFor(m=>m.Genre, ... From my answer

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of enum!